# Difference between NetInstall, HdMedia, and Live install images on UNetBootin?

Tags: system-installation, unetbootin

UNetBootin comes with three different choices for Ubunutu images: NetInstall, HdMedia, and Live.  What's the difference?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The short answer:

- Live refers to a system you can boot from CD/DVD or USB.
- Net-install installs the system on your hard-drive and it checks for
  updates for certain packages. Changes to the system are permanent.
- HdMedia means installing directly from the HDD, by booting the ISO.

Answer (score 4):

Derp, it's right there in the interface:

- The Live version allows for booting in Live mode, from which the installer can optionally be launched.
- The NetInstall version allows for installation over FTP, and can install Kubuntu and other official Ubuntu derivatives.
- If you would like to use a pre-downloaded alternate (not desktop) install iso, use the HdMedia option, and then place the alternate install iso file on the root directory of your hard drive or USB drive